# Oauth 1.0 compatiability with Amazon Oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit, oauth-1.0a, etsy

I'm currently working with PhpoAuthLib Library [Here](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib)

and i'm working with trying to integrate it into an Alexa skill for the Amazon echo. 
I have pretty much got the entire workflow and I am stumped on the last step as Amazon's error reporting is less than helpful and instead of giving a specific detail of whats going wrong, I get a generic 'the account could not be linked', error. Amazon developer forums are just as useless as the moderators seem to just direct you to the same documentation which I've read 10 times already to no success.

I've been using [this video as reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mO0gZPeR45o) and from what he says it sounds like it's possible to link an oauth 1.0 service to alexa, but im falling at the last hurdle. (at the 4:40 mark)

It's a pretty specific issue but maybe someone with some in depth knowledge of the two versions of oauth could help point out what would need to be handed back to Amazon to successfully link to the 2.0 service they have.

For some context, I'm trying to link an alexa skill to a users Etsy account, allowing them to access details of their account through voice control on the echo. Etsy Oauth is still 1.0, and amazon's account linking system is oauth 2.0.